# Underlined text inside WordPress header button cannot be removed

Tags: css, wordpress, button, wordpress-theme-astra

I was recently working on a WordPress project when I came across the underlined text in the picture below. It remains underlined until I hover over it, then the underline disappears.

Button BEFORE hovering over it

[image: Button BEFORE hovering over it]

Button AFTER hovering over it

[image: Button AFTER hovering over it]

I tried to change basically all settings regarding both the general buttons look and the specific design of the one in the website header.

I'm using the latest version of WordPress running the latest version of the Astra theme.

This is the first time I have encountered this problem, although I've worked on many other websites before and it always worked as expected.

Any Ideas?

Comment: It's not possible to help you if you do not post the code that you are using. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. What code should I post in this case? Because I'm just using the visual editor.

Comment: Well, you need to make use of Chrome Dev Tools or the developer tools of your browser to inspect the code. It can also be helpful if you can show your demo site but people here would prefer code through the snippet instead of a demo link which may expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was kindly suggested by m4no I dug a bit in the Chrome Dev Tools and found the CSS that was causing the underlining:

```
a:where(:not(.wp-element-button)) {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And changed it to

```
a:where(:not(.wp-element-button)) {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

in the Additional CSS which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be disabled via [theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/)

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
  "version": 2,
  "styles": {
    "elements": {
      "link": {
        "typography": {
          "textDecoration": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I didn't come up with this solution, it was suggested by user [straightvisions-matthias-bathke](https://pullanswer.com/users/straightvisions-matthias-bathke) in [another forum](https://pullanswer.com/questions/a-where-not-wp-element-button-is-overwriting-all-anchor-tags-on-site-in-14-0-3).